collect signals pending in the kernel driver
I want to log signal(s) coming from the user space to the driver's read() function terminating the waiting process (e.g. wait_interruptible). There're a number of system calls to manage the signals in the Linux kernel, but I can't find how to get the current state of signals like it is done with sigpending() in the user space.
Update: here's what I came up with after Ian Abbott's suggestion
    unsigned long int flags;
    spin_lock_irqsave(&current->sighand->siglock, flags);
    memmove((void*)&sigset, (void*)&current->pending.signal, sizeof(sigset));
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&current->sighand->siglock, flags);
    for(i = 1; i < _NSIG; i ++)
    {
        if(sigismember(&sigset, i))
        {
                ...
        }
    }

to find out that:

_NSIG is not 30 or even 32, but 64 (why???)
The only signal being logged is 9 (SIGKILL) when user space gets SIGINT (^C). At this point I am not sure the effort on logging the signal received has any sense at all as whatever user space gets the driver processing may simply be always killed with SIGKILL...


There is a set of task-specific pending signals in current->pending, a set of shared pending signals in current->signal->shared_pending and a set of blocked signals in current->blocked. All of those sets are stored as a sigset_t values. They should only be accessed with the current->sighand->siglock spinlock locked with IRQ disabled.

@IanAbbott thank you very much. Updated the question, will very appreciate your thoughts.

Q: Why is _NSIG 64? A: There are also real-time signals SIGRTMIN to SIGRTMAX. Also, the for loop should continue while i <= _NSIG.

SIGINT from the terminal will be sent to the foreground process group, so it will probably be set in the shared_pending signal set, although I must admit I have not thoroughly studied signal handling in the kernel!

@IanAbbott yes, SIGINT is set in shared pending signals.
